# How to disable or set to empty array model property $with to not eager load default model relations when needed?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have something like this:

```
class User
{
    protected $with = ['organisation'];
}

class Group
{
    public function members(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'groups_members', 'group_id', 'user_id', 'id', 'id')
                    ->select(['users.id', 'users.name', 'users.email']);
    }
}
```

How to prevent loading of organisation relation for group members?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `without()`:

```php
public function members(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'groups_members', 'group_id', 'user_id', 'id', 'id')
                ->select(['users.id', 'users.name', 'users.email'])
                ->without('organisation');
}
```